# How to broadcast a DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1 version.
creating a broadcast variable as below

```
Broadcast<Map<String,Dataset>> bcVariable = javaSparkContext.broadcast(//read dataset);
```

Me passing the bcVariable to a function

```
Service.calculateFunction(sparkSession, bcVariable.getValue());


public   static class Service {
        public static calculateFunction(
          SparkSession sparkSession,
          Map<String, Dataset> dataSet ) {

        System.out.println("---> size : " + dataSet.size());  //printing size 1


        for( Entry<String, Dataset> aEntry : dataSet.entrySet() ) {
           System.out.println( aEntry.getKey());   //  printing key 
            aEntry.getValue().show()   // throw null pointer exception
           }
    }
```

What is wrong here ? how to pass a dataset/dataframe in the function?

**Try 2 :**

```
Broadcast<Dataset> bcVariable = javaSparkContext.broadcast(//read dataset);
```

Me passing the bcVariable to a function

```
 Service.calculateFunction(sparkSession, bcVariable.getValue());
```

public   static class Service {
        public static calculateFunction(
          SparkSession sparkSession,
          Dataset dataSet ) {

```
    System.out.println("---> size : " + dataSet.size());  // throwing null pointer exception.



}
```

What is wrong here ? how to pass a dataset/dataframe in the function?

**Try 3 :**

```
Dataset metaData = //read dataset from oracle table i.e. meta-data.
```

Me passing the metaData to a function

Service.calculateFunction(sparkSession, metaData );

```
public   static class Service {
        public static calculateFunction(
          SparkSession sparkSession,
          Dataset metaData ) {

        System.out.println("---> size : " + metaData.size());  // throwing null pointer exception.



    }
```

What is wrong here ? how to pass a dataset/dataframe in the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value to be broadcast has to be any Scala object but not a `DataFrame`.

`Service.calculateFunction(sparkSession, metaData)` is executed on executors and hence metaData is `null` (as it was not serialized and sent over the wire from the driver to executors).

> **broadcast[T](value: T): Broadcast[T]**
>
> Broadcast a read-only variable to the cluster, returning a [org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast) object for reading it in distributed functions. The variable will be sent to each cluster only once.

Think of `DataFrame` data abstraction to represent a distributed computation that is described in a SQL-like language (Dataset API or SQL). It simply does not make any sense to have it anywhere but on the driver where computations can be submitted for execution (as tasks on executors).

You simply have to "convert" the data this computation represents (in `DataFrame` terms) using `DataFrame.collect`.

Once you collected the data you can broadcast it and reference using `.value` method.

---

The code could look as follows:

```
val dataset = // reading data
Broadcast<Map<String,Dataset>> bcVariable = 
  javaSparkContext.broadcast(dataset.collect);
Service.calculateFunction(sparkSession, bcVariable.getValue());
```

The only change compared to your code is `collect`.

Comment: Great explanation @Jacek Laskowski! But I got a question, after read a table from HBase/Hive, if you want that information to be in every single executor (streaming, can't be asking around)..the only way is making a collect (and broadcast)? Ins't this too detrimental for the performance? Pozdrawiam ;)

Comment: I don't think so. That's exactly how a broadcast hash join works in Spark SQL so if they, the Spark devs, do this I'm too lazy to think of a better alternative :)