# Broadcast Array[Row] and use it in a separate package

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to broadcast a Dataframe DF, by performing a
`val broadcastedDF = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(DF.collect())`
The next thing that I'm doing is, I've a POJO class with static
variables, to which I assign this broadcasted variable :
`setBroadCastDF(broadcastedDF, spark)`, I'm sending the `spark` object as well here.

What I want to acheive here is that, I've a UDF, where I want to use this Array[Row], recreate the DF using the schema and then perform some lookups on it. There is something that I think I'm missing, due to which I'm getting a NPE when trying to access the Broadcast variable in the UDF.

```
var dedupedDFValue = getBroadCastDF();
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("column_a", StringType, false) ::
    StructField("column_b", StringType, false) :: Nil)
println("Test if broadcast has value ? " + dedupedDFValue.value.take(10))
```

The last line throws the Null Pointer Exception here. Since my logic of creating the Broadcast variable and accessing it is split across files [2 files], I'm not understanding as performing what action would actually broadcast the data, so that the UDF can access it ? I created the POJO layer to solve this, but that is not working as expected.
Also, is it possible to share the `spark` object ? Few questions in SO says No, stating the `spark` object belongs to the driver, and no executor can access it, whereas few other questions says that it is possible to share the spark object.

Comment: The spark context is the initiation point for the driver to communicate with the spark cluster. So what is the need for you to share it? 
Also, it's not clear why you are collecting on your df, broadcasting it and then recreating it. Why not just broadcast the DF and perform all the operations you want on it? It would be more efficient.

Comment: Spark doesn't allow braodcasting the Dataframe, it need's to be a Scala object, which can be broadcasted. I'm trying to pass in the spark object as I want to recreate the Dataframe, which is only possible, when I have the sparkContext available to me @m_vemuri

Comment: Spark can broadcast variables or dataframes. Here's a link to the scala API: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@broadcast[T](df:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]
A similar function should also exist in the python API.


To clarify, If you are trying to copy data across all executors/nodes in spark, you can use broadcast to provide spark wth a hint to distribute the data and cache it in each machine. Also, spark is smart and will broadcast where appropriate. An example is joins b/w a large and small table.

Comment: what @m_vemuri says is correct. I think there is something wrong with your approach or understanding DebashisDeb

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya: My understanding is from this SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59373087/how-to-broadcast-a-dataframe . I think the issue in my code was : I was setting the POJO with the objects in the driver, and was trying to access that Object in executor, which won't be possible, since it stays in the driver. I'm trying to perform some action on the driver now, so that the data is pushed as needed. I'll update the thread, once I get some results.