# Broadcast DataFrame and Filter when joining a big with a small Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a big Dataframe with columns `user_id`, `user_address` and multiple user related columns (10-12 more) and a small (< 2MB) Dataframe with columns `user_id` and `user_contact`. Each user can have lots of phone numbers/email addresses.

I am trying to broadcast the smaller Dataframe and pass its data to an UDF. However, I am not able to get all the data present in each of the executors. As the UDF returns `No match found` if no contact details found for that user_id.

I try to filter the broadcastDF by the `user_id`, but seems like that is not working. Can someone please guide me here?

```scala
val DF = createDF("/somePath/")
val broadcastedDF = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(DF)
val DFWithUDF = someDF.select( col("user_id),
                               UDF(col("user_name"),
                               typedLit[Seq[String]](broadcastedDF.value.filter(broadcastedDF.value("user_id") === col("user_id")).
                                                        select("user_contact").
                                                        collect().map(data => 
                                                           String.valueOf(data.getAs[String]("user_contact")))
                                                      )
                                                    ).alias(SCHEMA_REQUEST_TARGET)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a join hint to broadcast the smaller Dataframe when joining those two Dataframes and there is no need to specifically broadcasting it yourself. Your code could look like:

```scala
val bigDf = ... // has columns user_id, user_address
val smallDf = ... // has columns user_id and user_contact

// define your join expression and join those tables using column user_id
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast
val joinExpr = bigDf.col("user_id") === smallDf.col("user_id")
val joinedDF = bigDf.join(broadcast(smallDf), joinExpr)
```

If your small Dataframe is smaller than 10MB and you did not change the configuration `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`, which defaults to 10MB you do not even need to mention the broadcast hint in your join.

The configuration `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` is described as:

> "Configures the maximum size in bytes for a table that will be broadcast to all worker nodes when performing a join. By setting this value to -1 broadcasting can be disabled. Note that currently statistics are only supported for Hive Metastore tables where the command ANALYZE TABLE  COMPUTE STATISTICS noscan has been run, and file-based data source tables where the statistics are computed directly on the files of data."

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But is it not possible to broadcast a dataframe directly ? Using the broadcast method available in SparkContext ?

Comment: Glad it helped. Regarding broadcasting a Dataframe, you can have a look [How to broadcast a DataFrame?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59373087/how-to-broadcast-a-dataframe).